# Reactor 3 'interval buffer' Flux?

Tags: project-reactor

How can I use existing Flux operators to make a Flux return incoming values into multiple Lists with a minimum delay between returns?

[image: 'interval buffer' Flux]

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with a non-trivial set of composed operators.

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.*;

import reactor.core.publisher.*;

public class DelayedBuffer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10)
        .flatMap(v -> Mono.delayMillis(v * 1000)
              .doOnNext(w -> System.out.println("T=" + v))
              .map(w -> v)
        )
        .compose(f -> delayedBufferAfterFirst(f, Duration.ofSeconds(2)))
        .doOnNext(System.out::println)
        .blockLast();
    }

    public static <T> Flux<List<T>> delayedBufferAfterFirst(Flux<T> source, Duration d) {
        return source
        .publish(f -> {
            return f.take(1).collectList()
            .concatWith(f.buffer(d).take(1))
            .repeatWhen(r -> r.takeUntilOther(f.ignoreElements()));
        });
    }
}
```

(Note however, that the expected emission pattern may be better matched with a custom operator due to time being involved.)

Comment: Thanks, it helped me, but I think this fits more my need:
.publish(f -> f.take(1).collectList()
 .concatWith(f.take(d).collectList()
  .filter(list -> !list.isEmpty())
  .repeatWhen(r -> r.takeWhile(n -> n > 0)))
 .repeatWhen(r -> r.takeUntilOther(f.ignoreElements())))

Answer (score 0):

I thought `buffer(Duration)` would fit your need, but it doesn't.

edit: leaving this in case someone with your exact same need is tempted to use that operator. This variant of buffer splits the sequence into consecutive time windows (that each produce a `buffer`). That is, the new `delay` starts at the end of the previous one, not whenever a new out-of-delay element is emitted.

Comment: No, with buffer() the delays will start each time another delay ends. I need that on each incoming value, if there's no current delay then return the value and start a delay, or buffer it if there's already a delay running.

Comment: left answer in place, edited to clarify why it isn't adapted